# How to check return value of function in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

If I step through a code in debugging and for something like below how to easily check the return value of the function?

```
for (i = 0; i < Count(); ++i)
```

I want to see the value of "Count()".

Comment: You can either save it into a temp variable, or step into the function and see what's returned. As return value is placed into EAX register, you can add `eax` to your `Watch` window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Autos** window Visual Studio automatically shows the returned value:

[image]